# How to read numbers only to list as integer, from a file using python

Tags: python

I have a txt file like this:

```
input 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0
output 127 191 223 239 247 251 253 254 0
```

I want to read integers `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0` to a list.
Here is my code:

```
f=open('data.txt','r')
for line in f:
        if 'input' in line:
                linestr=line.strip('input')
                #linestr=list(map(int,linestr)
                print(linestr)
```

The output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0
```

But when i add `"print(linestr[0]+1)"`, it shows error `"TypeError: must be str, not int"` 
Is that means the list I got is still not integer?
How can I use the number as int in this list?
Thx all

Comment: What is the point of `f_new =open ('data_out.c','w')`?

Comment: Your list is not a `list` it is a `str`. Try `print(type(linear))`... You even call it `linestr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still a string.  Test this by `type(linestr)`.  You cannot add an integer to a string.

What you need to do is extract each value from `liststr`.  This can be done easily using `strip()` and running through this list to get each value, next you need to pass it to `int()` to turn each value into an integer, append it to your list with integers, then you can use it as expected:

```
new_liststr = []
for i in liststr.split():
    new_liststr.append(int(i))

print(new_linestr[0]+1)
```

Or as a single liner:

```
new_liststr = [int(i) for i in liststr.split()] 
print(new_linestr[0]+1)
```

Comment: @RobynPan  No problem. Pleased I was helpful :)

Comment: Hi Simon. I got another question, If I want to add a list to a certain line in C file, for example, I want to change "int a[]={}" to "int a[] ={my list}" in c file, other lines stay the same in C file. Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: You could use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782114/write-and-replace-particular-line-in-file search through the file and replace the entire line @RobynPan

Answer (score 0):

You can not att a `str` and an `int` inside a `print()`

```
print(linestr[0]+1)
                 ^
                 |
             not a str
```

You can:

```
print(int(linestr[0])+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path
doc="""input 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0
output 127 191 223 239 247 251 253 254 0"""
Path('temp.txt').write_text(doc)

with open('temp.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'input' in line:
             linestr=line.strip('input')

# here is what you have accomplished:
assert linestr == ' 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0\n'
assert linestr == ' '
#you are tying to do ' '+1

linelist = map(int, linestr.strip().split(' '))
assert linestr[0]+1 == 1
```

P.S. your original import is a terrible workaround, please learn to use https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

```
output = []
with open('data.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        l = line.split()
        if l[0] == 'input':
            output.extend(map(int, l[1:]))
```