# Python: replace line in file without reading the entire file

Tags: python, file, sed, replace

I have a very large text file.
In that file, using python, I want to change line 3333 from `AABB` to `AA_BB`.
Since I know exactly which line I want to change, it seems pointless to open the entire file with `file.readlines()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719438/editing-specific-line-in-text-file-in-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45187646/python-how-to-write-to-specific-line-in-existing-txt-file), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782114/write-and-replace-particular-line-in-file).

I there an efficient way to do this? Something like `sed -i -e '3333s/AABB/AA_BB/'`?

Comment: You don't need to read the entire file, but you will have to seek from the beginning of the file to the line you wish to edit. This is because you have to count the number of new lines.

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719438/editing-specific-line-in-text-file-in-python

Comment: There is no other way to do this. Firstly you don't know where in the file the change needs to be apart from the line number. Secondly the change adds at least one character to the file. Both of these points add up to the need to read the whole file *and* to write back to the whole file.